# Sort a csv file alphabetically

Tags: python

I have this csv file:

```
ID,Name,Score1,Score2,Score3
100,Anne,3,4,5
101,Frank,1,2,3
102,Shawn,7,8,9
103,Bo,3,6,5
104,James,4,7,2
```

I want to sort the csv file in an alphabetically order by their names, like this:

```
ID,Name,Score1,Score2,Score3
100,Anne,3,4,5
103,Bo,3,6,5
101,Frank,1,2,3
104,James,4,7,2
102,Shawn,7,8,9
```

So far I´ve tried this:

```
def alphabetically_ordered(file_name):
Wanted_order = {"A":0,"B":1,"C":2,"D":3,"E": 4,"F":5,"G":6,"H":7,"I":8,"J": 9,"K":10,"L":11,"M":12,"N":13,"O":14,"P":15,"Q":16,"R":17,"S":18,"T": 19,"U":20,"V":21,"W":22,"X":23,"Y": 24,"Z":25,"Æ":26,"Ø":27,"Å":28}
with open('file_name','rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)
    data = sorted(csv_input,key=lambda x: (Wanted_order[x[1]], socket.inet_aton(x[0])))
    return data
```

But I get an Error message.

How do I sort my csv file alphabetically by the names?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: "iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)"

Comment: "rb" mode is not text mode - try changing to just "r". Or even just omit the mode argument, since "r" is the default.

Answer (score 4):

Using just `sorted` with `lambda` function in `key` should work.

**Ex:**

```
import csv
with open(filename, "rU") as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)
    data = sorted(csv_input, key=lambda x: x[1])
    print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[['100', 'Anne', '3', '4', '5'], ['103', 'Bo', '3', '6', '5'], ['101', 'Frank', '1', '2', '3'], ['104', 'James', '4', '7', '2'], ['102', 'Shawn', '7', '8', '9']]
```

*Edit as per comment*

```
with open(filename, "wb") as f_input:
    csv_out = csv.writer(f_input)
    csv_out.writerow(header)
    csv_out.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Your lambda is equivalent to `operator.itemgetter(1)`, which may be a bit faster, especially if the list being sorted is large.

Comment: If the names consists of a last name aswell. Is it the same methos still usefull?

Comment: Awesome!! Is it possible to make the output look like the format of the input?

Comment: my output right now does not contain the titles "ID,Name,Score1,Score2,Score3". Instead the whole output is looks like a long list. Is it possible to make the output look the same as the input but the only difference is that the names have been sorted alphabetically?

Comment: Updated snippet.

Comment: When I write the line 
header = next(csv_input)
I get a Error: StopIteration